# How to prevent or disable Bootstrap 4 popover auto positioning behavior (Self adjusting behavior)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using Bootstrap 4 framework in my project and using the popover for my requirement. While i'm using the popover I have noticed that the popover itself self adjusting the position when the viewport is changed from portrait to landscape.

The popover is having a fixed height and I have given the data-placement as bottom.
While switching from portrait to landscape it is self adjusting the position and changing to top position.

My requirement is that I need the popover placement as bottom in all screens and viewports and want to prevent its self adjusting behavior from bottom to top position.

While I investigate the issue i found that the height is exceeding from the View port height and hence causing the issue.

Any help or solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

```
Link : `https://jsbin.com/paladipepi/1/edit?html,css,js,output`
```

Step to reproduce:

1) Open the link `https://jsbin.com/paladipepi/1/edit?html,css,js,output`,output output in Chrome browser

2) Open the emulator and select any mobile device (iPhone6/iPhoneX) and click the popover.

3) Switch to landscape mode

Expected result: Should be placed as bottom

Actual result : Auto adjusting to the top position.

Code

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  trigger: 'focus'
})
})
```

```css
.subheader{
  position:sticky;
}

.popover-body{
  height:340px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  </header>
  <div class="subheader">
    
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popver 1</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popver 2</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popver 3</a>
</nav>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
  

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @RachelGallen Thanks for ur response. Updated with code. Please have a look

Comment: How's it going? Question looks much better now :)

Comment: Same issue exist. It is self adjusting the bottom position to top position while switching from portrait to landscape mode in devices (iPhoneX). Tested in Chrome emulator

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I'm using an android 8  (HTC ) .. the popover stays in same position relative to the navbar? Is that not what you hope for? Is it solely an Ios issue?

Comment: No actually I want the same position in bottom. I want to prevent its self adjusting behavior from bottom position to top position. (need popover data-placement as bottom in all cases. Now it is self adjusting to top position when the height of the popover-body is exceeding from the viewport height. That might be the issue. I want to prevent this behavior)

Comment: Can u please switch to landscape mode. :)

Comment: I did. And I just tested it on an old iphone 5. The popover isn't responsively sizing, that's the biggest issue as I see it. On the android on landscape I couldn't see the bottom, on the iphone in landscape i couldn't see top or bottom, only the middle!

Comment: I suggest using something other than px to size it, maybe a % height with position relative or/and set margin so that it's same top and bottom  - vertical-align middle might work (although it rarely does in my experience!!). Tricky. Definitely address the pixel issue

Comment: My bad. Hope you didn't understand my question. Top position means literally the behavior of the bootstrap popover placement. Just to make it more clear if it is bottom the arrow will be the top position of the popover and if it is top then the arrow will be bottom position 
Presently it is in the middle it is changing the behavior of popover from bottom to top when the popover height is exceeding from the viewport height.
Please observe the arrow position and after that remove the fixed height from the popover-body class and check the behavior again. Hope u got it. :)

Comment: i can't change the height. This popover contains the filter sort option and having a min-height of 340px. It will increase as per the user selects the filter option. By default it contains 5 options which will have the min-height of 340px.

Comment: I couldn't tell where the arrow was on landscape on iphone 5, on portrait the arrow was on bottom. On android the arrow was at bottom both ways

Comment: it's not very user-friendly to not have an adjustable size, filter or no filter. Add a scroll if you must, but at the moment, u must increase your user experience

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is the client requirement and I couldn't change that. I'm unable to upload the image from my company network. I will soon update this with images. Hope that will help to understand the issue. I would really appreciate your time and effort u took for this and expecting the help after uploading the images. :)

Comment: I understand the issue after your description of top etc. But problem is I couldn't even see the arrow on iOS, and that is a bigger problem than the arrow being in the wrong place. I have things to do now but good luck with resolving the issue

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen for your support. :) Have a great day. :)

Comment: Hi @RacelGallen. I got the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hooray !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Got the solution

set the fallbackPlacement to  ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'] in Bootstrap Popover options

```
Link: https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html#modifiers..flip.behavior

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            container: '.subheader',
            fallbackPlacement : ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom']
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel :)

Comment: In attribute form: data-fallback-placement='["left","right","top","bottom"]'

Answer (score 0):

Popover is based out of popper.js. The position is defined to 'bottom' but whenever you see it in iphone landscape mode, the popover has not room to display it in bottom position because of it's height of 340px, hence forcing it to render from top (this behavior is right though). Now to your requirements you could try removing the height of `.popover-body` on iphone landscape or reduce it, using `media queries` and set `height` to `100%` of html and body.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hi @Kunal Yes i tried those possibilities by reducing the height and adding the overflow-y:scroll to the popover-body while switching to landscape using jquery and it works!!!! But it is the client requirement and I coudn't change that. Is there is any other possbile way to prevent this behaviour.?

Comment: I don't think that there are any other workaround to do this. Because on phone, things are needed to be adjusted. We can't keep height to 340px in window of 414px.

Comment: But we can scroll the body content right..? The popover should scroll with body content with fixed position. Is it a possible workaround. I tried but couldn't achieve it.?

Comment: Yup, that's might be the only solution in this scenario. But I don't think so that it will be possible with bootstrap. You may try some external jquery library for it, for eg : 'tooltipster'. That might help!!!

Comment: I can do it with popper.js itself. I have created a new popover using popper.js and I already suggest these options but the customer needs to prevent the self adjusting bootstrap 4 behavior. Is it possible..?

Answer (score 0):

Just set container and boundary to body, also set all fallback placements to bottom

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'focus',
    container: 'body',
    boundary: 'body',
    fallbackPlacement: ['bottom','bottom','bottom','bottom']
  })
})
```

https://jsbin.com/nojavagane/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

set the fallbackPlacement to 'counterclockwise' and position container to 'relative'

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        container: '.container',
        html: true,
        trigger:'manual',
        fallbackPlacement: 'counterclockwise'
    })
```